# How can I make relationship between two Java classes?

Tags: java

I want to know how to maintain relation ship between two classes in Java without using any frame work and database.

EX: Suppose I have Company and Employee classes.
So, if I have Company Object with me, how can I find out Employees related to this company and vice versa.

Please help me.

Comment: you can still use frameworks like hibernate without a full blown application server

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to have the `Company` class contain a list of employees.

```
public class Company {
    private List<Employee> employees;
}

class Employee {
    private String name;
}
```

Obviously there are multiple ways to implement this, so it depends on your needs.

Comment: +1 Java doesn't have a concept of relationships and how you associate them is entirely up to you. This suggestion is as good as any.